# Create-react-app error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I would like to use create-react-app, so I follow the instruction:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

But I have error on last step. After running `npm start` I get error:

> Could not find an open port at linux-llw5. Network error message:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND linux-llw5

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your machine probably has a global `HOST` environment variable so Create React App tries to find an open port on it instead of the default `localhost`. Delete the environment variable and it should work fine as you want.

Alternatively you can explicitly change `start` in `scripts` in `package.json` to run `HOST=localhost react-scripts start`. But this seems a bit complex.

Comment: what is environment variable and how to delete it?

Answer (score 4):

If you set variable in command line and run

```
...
cd my-app/
HOST=localhost npm start
```

application should start correctly