# Brand new react/node.js project wont run on opensuse

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-native, npm

I'm currently learning Express and react right now and was able to run react app originally. While starting a new web app(Yesterday), I was not able to prevent a freshly created react app from crashing.

```
My OS:
openSUSE 20180522 <br>
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.16.9-1-default
```

The error:

```
$ npm start

 > movieapp@0.1.0 start 
 /home/knosence/Templates/syntelBootCamp/react/movieapp
 > react-scripts start

 Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: linux-gz59
 If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it 
 in your shell.
 Learn more here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration

 events.js:183
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND linux-gz59
     at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! movieapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Failed at the movieapp@0.1.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /home/knosence/.npm/_logs/2018-05-24T20_48_01_951Z- 
 debug.log
```

`

```
$ cat /home/knosence/.npm/_logs/2018-05-24T20_48_01_951Z-debug.log<br> 
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node8', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.0.1
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~prestart: movieapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~start: movieapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/knosence/Templates/syntelBootCamp/react/movieapp/node_modules/.bin:/home/knosence/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/knosence/Templates/syntelBootCamp/react/movieapp
10 silly lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle movieapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: movieapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:283:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid movieapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/knosence/Templates/syntelBootCamp/react/movieapp
16 verbose Linux 4.16.9-1-default
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node8" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.0.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error movieapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the movieapp@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

`

If anyone can help me with this then it will be greatly appreciated!! If anyone needs more information, let me know and I will provide. Thanks!

Comment: It may be a [hosts file problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259697/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-in-nodejs-for-get-call)

Comment: I provided an answer in the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63566465/4501494

Answer (score 0):

Your machine probably has a global `HOST` environment variable so Create React App tries to find an open port on it instead of the default `localhost`. Delete the environment variable and it should work fine as you want.

Maybe this answer will help you.

[Create-react-app error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826017/create-react-app-error/44830423#44830423)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and fixed it using

```
HOST=localhost npm start
```

Hope that it helps anyone else!